# RAID to handle 800 random blocks per second

Tags: hard-drive, performance, raid-5

This is a homework. We are supposed to pick HDD, imagine we are buidling RAID to handle 800 random blocks per second (550 reads/250 writes).

I have picked RAID5 made out of 3 HDDs. But it is too slow.

- 8KiB block size (8192 bytes)
- Access time 16ms (benchmarked my WD Caviar)
- transfer rate 142MB/s (benchmarked my WD Caviar)

1 block from 1 HDD at 142MB/s = 8192B/142MBps = 0.05769 ms

= 16+0.06 = 16.06 = 16ms

Writting data 2*16ms (data+parity) = 32ms

So for 550reads+250writes it is 550*16 + 250*32 ms = 16.8s

Are my calculations off or is the RAID configuration wrong? Could you point me in a right direction? What RAID config do you recommend?

**Ok, I have managed with RAID10 made from 4+4 10k RPM HDDs.**

Comment: Both! You forgot the read part of the parity and getting 800IOPS from 3xWD Caviar in RAID5 belongs in a category of 3 days ago.

Comment: Coud you point me in a right direction?

Comment: If it is homework, then you shouldn't be asking others to do it for you.

Comment: Just give me a hint. How can I make it handle 800 random blocks per second when 800*16ms > 1s?

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please add it as an actual answer. And while you’re at it, why not include the calculations as well? ;)